# How do I use a thread pool to write to my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord, thread-safety

I'm using the thread pool discussed in https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread to spawn multiple downloaders.

I'm trying to download the contents of many RSS feeds, nearly 200K feeds in total, but I'm having issues with locking and concurrency in my MySQL database when calling ActiveRecord's `save` method.

I'm pretty sure I need to designate a single thread for interacting with the database and send signals to this thread, but I'm not exactly sure how to structure this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at Ruby's [Queue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0//libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) class.

Create a queue that is used to hold the record information prior to sending the data to your database. All your RSS threads write to it as "producers".

Create a new thread that only reads from that queue and writes to the database as the "consumer". It should have no trouble keeping ahead of the RSS threads.

You'll want to `join` the main code to all the threads, including the DB consumer, so all threads complete before the app can quit otherwise you could end up with unwritten records.

Since you showed no source code there is no way we can help you integrate this, but it should be easy to do.